# Implication in Logarithmic Inequalities

Tags: inequality, logarithms

I am trying to understand an implication I came across in a research article, and I was wondering if someone could provide more details or clarifications on the reasoning behind it.

The inequality in question is as follows:

$\frac{1}{p} > \frac{\log(p)}{\log(n) \cdot \log(\log(n))}$

where $p$ is the greatest prime in the factorization of $n$
and the claim is that this implies $p < \log n$.

I was wondering if someone could explain the steps that leads to this conclusion. Is there any specific logarithmic property or manipulation that directly justifies $p < \log n$? Or is some additional context needed that hasn't been shared?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $n > e$ (so that the denominator on the right is positive) the inequality is equivalent to
$$
 p \cdot \log(p) < q \cdot \log(q)
$$
with $q := \log(n) > 1$. Since the function $x \mapsto x \cdot \log(x)$ is  strictly increasing on $[1, \infty)$ it follows that $p < q$.

(The fact that $p$ is a prime factor of $n$ is not needed for this conclusion, only that $p \ge 1$ and $n > e$.)